# Exporting from Spotfire to PowerPoint - ignores alignment

Tags: export, powerpoint, analytics, spotfire, tibco

Encountered an issue where exporting same report on 2 different domains - gives different results.

When I export on my network then all is fine. There are headers and Logo's on analytics and all are centred.

When same report is exported from client side the alignments are ignored.
Some blank pages appear. Font sizes are smaller.
I tested on multiple machines and applied same setting but on our network it worked fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there's not a lot of information here, but it could be a bug in the Spotfire Server.

please make sure your software is up to date on hotfixes from [support.tibco.com](http://support.tibco.com).

if you update to the latest hotfix and still see the issue, and your version of spotfire is still supported, open up a support ticket at [support.tibco.com](http://support.tibco.com).

Comment: Yeah that's what we did. Investigation of problem is still on going. It is a weird issue as even in web client on same report. When client opened it alignments were wrong without even exporting.